# get url params in Action compositions

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a Interceptor (Action compositions) defined for my controllers.
I need to access my url params in the request

i.e. for an entry in conf below, how would I access the Id paramter inside my Action composition?

```
GET /jobs/:id controllers.JobManager.getlist(id: Int)
```

my Action method interceptor class only has reference to my Http.Context object. while access to the body of the request is evident the url param is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract it yourself. In your example path is 6 characters long plus length of id.

```
String path = ctx.request().path();
String id = path.substring(6, path.length());
```

This solution depends on route's length. Alternatively, you can pass the start and end parameters to your action:

```
@With({ ArgsAction.class })
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Args {

    int start() default -1;
    int end() default -1;

}
```

And use it in action class to extract parameter:

```
public class ArgsAction extends Action<Args> {

    @Override
    public Promise<Result> call(Context ctx) throws Throwable {
        final int start = configuration.start();
        final int end = configuration.end();
        if (start != -1) {
            final String path = ctx.request().path();
            String arg = null;
            if (end != -1) {
                arg = path.substring(start, end);
            } else {
                arg = path.substring(start, path.length());
            }
            // Do something with arg...
        }
        return delegate.call(ctx);
    }
}
```

Usage in JobManager controller:

```
@Args(start = 6)
public getlist(Integer id) {
    return ok();
}
```